# How to find out if a word starts with a vowel

Tags: java

I need to find out if a word in a file starts with a vowel or not, and I know how to do it but my if statement is very inefficient. I had to put the words from my tokenizer into an arrayList and then use an if statement that uses .startsWith() 5 different times to account for each vowel. Is there potentially a faster way to do it?

```
    while (s.hasMoreTokens()){
        word = s.nextToken();
        list.add(word);
        if (list.get(i).startsWith("a")||list.get(i).startsWith("e")||list.get(i).startsWith("i")||list.get(i).startsWith("o")||list.get(i).startsWith("u")) {
            vowelCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't add it you your list and make your test on the `word` object, it will be a bit simplier. Though you won't have a really quicker way to do it, as you will have to test each vowel

Comment: What do you mean by inefficient ? Is your code really to slow for your recommandation ? Or you just mean "I feel it a little too long to read" ?

Comment: @vincrichaud I'm just wondering if there is a nicer way to write it

Comment: @ZakiMachfj-GlenforestSS21 Ok, so could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50177076/edit) your question to make clear that you just look for a better way to write, not a more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you may have 3 distinct objectives:

1) is it  language sensitive? If so, the concept of a vowel is tricky and will likely be delegated to some internationalization (i18n) annoying stuff I won't cover here.

2) tight code, but not necessarily faster:

```
boolean startWithVowel(String word) {
    return "eaiouEAIOU".indexOf(word.charAt(0)) >=0
}
```

3) fast but verbose code:

```
boolean startWithVowel(String word) {

    switch(word.charAt(0)) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

or

```
//in class definition:
static final boolean[] vowels = new byte['u'+1];
static {
    vowels['a'] = vowels['A'] = vowels['e'] = vowels['E'] = ..... = true;
}

boolean startWithVowel(String word) {
    int index = word.chartAt(0);
    return index<='u' && vowels[index]);
}
```

Please allow for sanity checks like word.lenght>0 somewhere of course.
(whatever you do, avoid regex if speed is a concern)

Comment: What if I want to print the word, would I have to add println() for each case?

Comment: @ZakiMachfj-GlenforestSS21: I'm only giving you the vowel test, which you could wap in a function (typically inlined by jit compiler anyway).

Comment: I meant for your switch case, how could I potentially print the words that meet the condition,

Comment: Really? just write some code before the return statement. Do you want the complete code for your implementation?

Comment: @ZakiMachfj-GlenforestSS21: I rewrote a bit what I meant.

Comment: @AngelAvila if you could do that, that would be great :)

Comment: Yes, I will send you a Paypal link, then I can do for you what you want. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your vowels is independent of the check. So begin with create new `Set<Char>` for it

Then you can test using the first character of string:

```
Set<Char> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('e', 'i', ...));
while (s.hasMoreTokens()){
    word = s.nextToken();
    list.add(word);
    if (word.length() > 0 && vowels.contains(word.charAt(0))) {
        vowelCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use  [`Set.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) to create an unmodifiable set. Also, for a real application, one would declare this `Set` as `public static final`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do that is:

```
       while (s.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word = s.nextToken();
            list.add(word);
            switch (word.charAt(0)) {
                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'o':
                case 'u':
                    // do something
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What am I supposed to put for default:

Comment: What you want, or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is like this :

```
boolean startWithVowel(String word) {    
   return word.startsWith(RegExp(r'[aeiouyAEIOUY]'))
}
```

You can add as many vowels as you want.